# update existing item in list using realm

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to update existing list item in `Realm` for a specific id.

here is my json structure

[image]

i want to change name of rec id #102 from Remeo to Abby.

```
RealmResults<Appointment> checkData = realm.where(Collage.class).equalTo("EmployeeList.empid","102").findAll().where().equalTo("EmployeeList.empid","102").findAll();

   if(checkData.size() > 0){


       checkData.get(0).getEmployeeLists().remove(0);
       checkData.get(0).getEmployeeLists().add(newEmployeeListItem);           
       realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(checkData);

   }
```

if i have more fields in EmployeList item , for example

`empid , empname , empaddress , empphone etc`

then in that case i want to replace the whole EmployeList item if it exist in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// in transaction
Employee employee = realm.where(Employee.class).equalTo("empid", 102).findFirst();
if(employee != null)  employee.setName("Abby");
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Well this can be done where u know tht name has changed but wht if I have 10 fields in employee list item and user has changed 5 items from tht. I want to replace the whole list item how do I do tht

Comment: Same way as I said.  You need to access the given realm object,  write the data into it,  and commit. You can however also call `removeFromRealm()` on the object and add another with the same ID,  but for that you still have to select the object.

Comment: Technically, to remove from the list, you have to remove it from the realm, using `removeFromRealm()` on the item.